# Context Switching and Timer Interrupts in xv6

Tags: c, xv6

I am trying to modify the scheduling policy in xv6 in which Parent runs first after forking.

```
childPid = fork();
    if (childPid < 0)
    {
        printf("fork() is failed\n");
    }
    else if (childPid == 0) // child
    {
        printf(" child! ");
        exit();
    }

    printf(" parent! ");
```

As the scheduler of xv6 always run Parent first i need to context switch to child first so that child will run first and after that parent will run.
I have tried using wait() in the code but the wait will fail and i do not want to use fail.
I need to modify the context switch when fork is performed by my user level program.

In the xv6 fork() system call i have made the following changes

```
  acquire(&ptable.lock);
  np->state = RUNNABLE;
  swtch(&cpu->scheduler, proc->context);
  release(&ptable.lock);
```

but this does not seems to work.
Does it have something to do with timer interrupts.
How can i achieve to run child first in fork after doing context switching.

Comment: The premise that *"wait will fail"* seems wrong. How did you come to that conclusion? Also, it might help to put `\n` at the end of the `printfs`.

Comment: What would 'Timer interrupts' have to do with anything here?

Comment: The child code could immediately inhibit all interrupts, so the scheduler could not run (this is a VERY drastic method and I recommend against it)

Comment: In xv6 fork system call i have made the changes to the swtch to run the newly created process first `fork()` method by adding above mentioned second code snippet. But after printing my child block my xv6 halts and doesnot run the parent code what can be done for parent to run again

Comment: @user3386109 : Yes it will fail if you go through the code of 'wait()' command in proc.c you can surely comment why it will fail. `if(!havekids || proc->killed){
   //cprintf("havekids %d ",havekids);
      release(&ptable.lock);
      return -1;
    }`

Comment: Umm, a) the parent has a kid, and b) the parent should probably handle the case where the kid is SIG_KILLed. OTOH, the parent could just ignore the return value from `wait`, and/or you could restrain yourself from SIG_KILLing the kid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use call [sched_yield()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_yield.2.html) in the parent code, this will make parent thread to to relinquish the CPU and the other thread will get to run.

Comment: *"the other thread will get to run"* temporarily at least, but there's no guarantee that the other thread will get anything done before the scheduler switches back to the parent.

Comment: the instruction following the call to sched_yield() should be waitpid( childpid, &status)  then the parent will sit and wait until the child has exited before continuing execution.

Comment: I cannot use sched_yield in this. I have already tried 'yield()' defined in proc.c of xv6 but its of no use.